# 'Input string was not in a correct format'

Tags: c#, datetime

Im trying to a program when you open it there is a label and it uses datetime to get your current hour by 24hour and make a welcome message. But when i try to get hour by 24hours it gives me error in the title.

my code:

```
        private void Window1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            string date_by_string = date.ToString("H"); ==> System.FormatException

            int time = int.Parse(date_by_string);
            string username = Environment.UserName + "!";

            MessageBox.Show("Good morning, " + username);

            if (time > 5 && time < 12)
            {
                WelcomeLabel_Label.Content = "Good morning, " + username;
            }
            else if (time > 11 && time < 18)
            {
                WelcomeLabel_Label.Content = "Good afternoon, " + username;
            }
        }
```

I tried to make another variable to define date_by_string, it was actually like this:

```
string date_by_string = DateTime.Now.ToString("H");
```

it didnt work either

Comment: `H` is not a Standard Format-String for `DateTime` values. What makes you think it is?

Comment: Why don't you simply take the value of the [DateTime.Hour property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.hour?view=net-7.0), like `int time = date.Hour;`? There is no need to create and parse a string representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the fact that `"H"` isn't a [standard format string for `DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#table-of-format-specifiers), it really doesn't make much sense to convert the datetime to a string and then parse it to an int to get the hour of the day, when `DateTime` aleardy has an int property for [`Hour`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.hour?view=net-7.0).
Also, your messagebox text doesn't change according to the hour, so I took the liberty of changing that as well.

A better code would simply use that property:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
var time = date.Hour;

string username = Environment.UserName + "!";

if (time > 5 && time < 12)
{
    WelcomeLabel_Label.Content = "Good morning, " + username;
}
else if (time > 11 && time < 18)
{
    WelcomeLabel_Label.Content = "Good afternoon, " + username;
}

MessageBox.Show(WelcomeLabel_Label.Content);
```

Answer (score 2):

.NET's `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` types have 2 different types of format-string:

1. *Standard* date and time format strings

   - These are **single-character** *shorthand* format-strings, like `g` ("General") and `d` ("Short date").
2. *Custom* date and time format strings

   - These are format-strings comprised of **two or more** characters, which represent one or more *specifiers*.
   - e.g. `yyyy-MM-dd` or `HH:mm`

When a single-character `format` String is passed to `DateTime.ToString(String format)` then .NET will always interpret it as a *Standard* format string - however `H` is not a Standard format string: it is a *Custom* format string.

[To use a single-character Custom format string with `ToString` you need to prefix it with `%` so .NET knows it isn't a *Standard* format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#UsingSingleSpecifiers):

Change your code to this:

```
string date_by_string = date.ToString("%H");
```

[But as @Clemens pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76661626/input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format/76661675#comment135158991_76661626): you should not be using `ToString` to get the values of date-time components: instead use the `.Hour` property to get the numeric value directly:

Also, consider structuring your `if/elseif` structure to use mutually-exclusive range checks, which is easier to follow:

```
private void Window1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int timeOfDayHours = DateTime.Now.Hour; // `timeOfDayHours` will be in the range 0-23 (inclusive).
    string username = Environment.UserName + "!";

    if( timeOfDayHours < 5 )
    {
        // NOOP
    }
    else if( timeOfDayHours < 12 )
    {
        this.WelcomeLabel_Label.Content = "Good morning, " + username;
    }
    else if( timeOfDayHours < 18 )
    {
        this.WelcomeLabel_Label.Content = "Good afternoon, " + username;
    }
    else // i.e. `timeOfDayHours >= 18 && timeOfDayHours <= 23`:
    {
        // NOOP
    }
}
```

Comment: Apparently my answer has earned two downvotes without any explanation or constructive-feedback...

Comment: Upvoted for compensation... while it was a decent answer when I completed mine, it's now an even better answer (even though you've missed that `MessageBox.Show`)

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thank you - I removed the `MessageBox.Show` line as it looks like scratch-code, and is redundant given the `WelcomeLabel_Label` logic below.

Comment: I think, I'd prefer pattern matching switch if on a version where that's available, but that's not a reason to dv this?

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods I don't like using C#'s _pattern matching_ features, mainly because I don't consider it "real" pattern-matching (compared to, say, Haskell or Rust): the C# compiler doesn't use the match-expressions to refine an interval-type representing the subject, and its check for exhaustiveness is very rudimentary. Until C# gets true interval-types and the C# compiler performs type-narrowing as part of flow-checking, I'm giving it a miss.

Comment: @Dai and that's totally fair. As I wrote: personal preference. What I wanted to say was: DVs seem to be somewhat arbitrary sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can replace the line where you use `.ToString` with the following to get the hours from today:

```cs
var date = DateTime.Now;
date.Hour;
```

The reason this gives an exception because “H” is just a single character and not a [supported format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings). Another solution could be to use a supported format and trim the output string, or use [custom formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings). Hope this helps!

Good luck!